# Querying and filtering results but sub-fields within each object

Tags: apex, soql, query, compile-error

If I have some object A, that has fields

```
Name(string), B__c (sObject) and C__c (sObject)
```

B__c has the fields

```
Name(string), BB__c (string of "Yes", "No" and "Maybe)
```

and C__c has the fields

```
Name(string), CC_c (bool)
```

how would I filter such that I can get all A's where

```
A.B__c.BB__c == "Yes" and A.C__c.CC__c == true
```

I basically tried the following but I got an error about sObject

```
return [
        SELECT Id, Name, B__c, C__c
        FROM A
        WHERE B__c.BB__c = :"Yes"
        And C__c.CC__c = :true
    ];
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with the Communities feature? Also, please include your error message ***verbatim*** in your post. Saying you got an error but not telling us what it was is not very informative.

Comment: Sorry, did this have to be communities? I'm not really sure where the communities thing you're mentioning is comin from

Comment: You added the `[community]` tag. By doing so you indicated this question us related to that feature.

Comment: @user49458, please consider accepting the below post if it addressed your question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pull in parent fields, the syntax is to use the Relationship Name, not the API Name of the Lookup field. Typically, that would look like:

- API Name: `Parent__c`
- Relationship Name: `Parent__r`

So the proper way to perform a [`Right Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join) would look more like:

```
SELECT Name__c, ParentB__c, ParentC__c
FROM A__c
WHERE ParentB__r.SomeField = 'Some Value'
AND ParentC__r.SomeCheckbox = true
```

Note that double quotes are not allowed in Apex nor SOQL, and you do not need to use query merge syntax (`:value`) for literal filter values.